# Implementing sequenceAL for lists

Tags: haskell, applicative

[Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) (Haskell Wiki) has this exercise in Applicative's section:

```
Implement a function
sequenceAL :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
```

I could only do it, if used the do notation (requiring Monad f to be added to the context:

```
sequenceAL :: (Monad f, Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceAL [] = pure []
sequenceAL (x:xs) = do
                     y <- x
                     ys <- sequenceAL xs
                     pure ([y] ++ ys)
```

How do I achieve this without using the do-notation and monads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can use `<$>` and `<*>` operator in [Control.Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) to do it:

```
sequenceAL :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceAL [] = pure []
sequenceAL (x:xs) = (:) <$> x <*> sequenceAL xs
```